# Magento add/edit page error debugging mystery

Tags: php, magento

because I'm a 'PHP guy' I was handed a Magento task today.  This is my first time ever doing anything other than minor CSS edits to a template w/ the software.  Never touched the Zend framework either.

I was handed a task to ***debug add/edit CMS pages***.  Due to my green horns, I'm sure I'm going about this all wrong.

Issue Summary

- I can't seem to land on 'expected results' when I attempt to add new pages or edit existing page content.  When I save I expect 1) for the content to make it's way in to the db and 2) for a message back from the application confirming that my add/edit was successful.  At this point, I'm getting neither.
- If I elect to edit a URL Key (to one that doesn't already exist) I am able to edit.
- When I attempt edit content, I'm dumped back to CMS > Pages when I hit either the `Save Page` or `Save and Continue Edit` button.

Info about our Install

- We're working with a 1.7.0.2 install
- We have 2 domains pointed at this install
- Apache: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5     mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 mod_jk/1.2.32

---

- I've looked in the following locations for pertinent error/log messages and found nothing

  - Apache error log
  - exception.log
  - system.log
  - the browser display

Is there a 1000' view of how to debug magento code or any tips/tricks you'd be willing to share with this noob?

Comment: This may help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146

Comment: Logging may be off in your system.